# NoMethodError Building a simple CMS in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I've been following along with [this tutorial from lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Nesting-pages-subjects/139989/159156-4.html).

I'm in chapter 15: Nesting pages in subjects

So I've followed through and have even resorted to just copying the exercise files they provide you with.  However I keep getting this error:

NoMethodError in PagesController#new
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

It hi-lights the second line:

```
def new
  @page = Page.new({:subject_id => @subject.id, :name => "Default"})
  @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
  @page_count = Page.count + 1
end
```

Here's my controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  layout "admin"

  before_action :confirm_logged_in
  before_action :find_subject

  def index
    # @pages = Page.where(:subject_id => @subject.id).sorted
    @pages = @subject.pages.sorted
  end

  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @page = Page.new({:subject_id => @subject.id, :name => "Default"})
    @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
    @page_count = Page.count + 1
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)
    if @page.save
      flash[:notice] = "Page created successfully"
      redirect_to(:action => 'index', :subject_id => @subject_id)
    else
      @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
      @page_count = Page.count + 1
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
    @page_count = Page.count
  end

  def update
    # Find an existing object using form parameters
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    # Update the object
    if @page.update_attributes(page_params)
      # If update succeeds, redirect to the index action
      flash[:notice] = "Page updated successfully"
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @page.id, :subject_id => @subject_id)
    else
      # If the update fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
      @page_count = Page.count
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    page = Page.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Page '#{page.name}' destroyed successfully"
    redirect_to(:action => 'index', :subject_id => @subject_id)
  end

  private

    def page_params
      # Same as using "params[:subject]", except that it:
      # - raises as error if :subject is not present
      # - allows listed attributes to be mass-assigned
      params.require(:page).permit(:subject_id, :name, :permalink, :position, :visible)
    end

    def find_subject
      if params[:subject_id]
        @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
      end
    end

end
```

Then here's the view:

```
<% @page_title = "New Page" %>

<%= link_to("<< Back to list", {:action => 'index', :subject_id => @subject_id}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="pages new">
    <h2>Create Page</h2>

    <%= form_for(:page, :url => {:action => 'create', :subject_id => @subject_id}) do |f| %>

      <%= render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}) %>

      <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= submit_tag("Create page") %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

A question similar to this one [has been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447964/pages-instance-variable-is-nilnillclass-building-a-simple-cms-in-rails/23816053?noredirect=1#comment36639327_23816053), but I don't see any solutions there.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Depending on the files you copied over, you may need to restart your server.

Comment: Tried that a couple of times with no success.

Comment: Make sure you have subjects records in your table.If there no record,@subject will be nill.

Comment: can you paste the params coming through in the request?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand quite what you mean @Pavan.  Still pretty new to this.

Comment: It says that there are no params from the request.

Comment: Your subjects table contain data in it?

Comment: Ah, yes there is data there.  I've got three different subjects.

Comment: Try changing the line `if params[:subject_id]` to `if params[:page][:subject_id]` in your `find_subject` method

Comment: So that messed thing sup further.  I wasn't able to view my pages within each subject then.  Gave me an undefined method error.

Comment: Total lack of sleep has one this round. Simple typo is what threw absolutely everything off.

subject_id should be subject.id

Seriously can't believe I did that. Thanks for trying to help guys, I really appreciate it. Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in

```
Page.new({:subject_id => @subject.id, :name => "Default"})
```

@subject is not defined and you are asking for its id

Answer (score 0):

You have to define @subject.

Put this as first line in your new action

```
@subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
```

Right now @subject is undefined therefore it's nil, calling .id on nil is resulting in the error you're seeing.